# Find installed package SHA hash in R

Tags: r, github, commit, sha, remotes

I have installed a package from GitHub in R long ago using `remotes::install_github`. Since then, the package has had several new commits, and all the commits have the same package version. I want to find out which GitHub commit was the one I installed the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package_info()` can be used:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
package_info("<package_name>")
```

Comment: This doesn't show anything more than sessionInfo() does